# How to find and extract a numeric value from a text file?

Tags: parsing, file-io, fortran

I have a file called "RFEM_Information.txt" which has 13 lines.

```
[None]======================================================================
        <Drainage>DrainedUndrained</Drainage>
        <Scr>0</Scr>
        <UseCavitationCutOff>No</UseCavitationCutOff>
        <pt>100</pt>
        <E>30</E>
        <Nu>0.25</Nu>
        <K>20</K>
[None]======================================================================
[Log][None]No OF NODES     = 474
[Log][None]
[Log][None]BEST STSR = 1.528
[Log] [None]=================================================================
```

I want to find line 12 (in general the line number is unknown) which has "[Log][None]BEST STSR = 1.528" and I want to extract the number or all the information of the line after "=" (I want to return as a number `1.528`).

How can I find the relevant line and read the value from it?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You did not ask a question. Please ask a question and refer to the linked help page for onstructions how to write a good one.

Comment: Do you actually want to ask how to parse a text string that contains some substring to extract a numeric value? We might have some similar existing questions but it is OK to ask for some generic how to, if it has not been asked before. But please do ask a question.

Comment: Dear @VladimirFГероямслава, ado you know how to solve it?

Comment: Please do take the [tour], read the help and then [edit] your post to contain an actual question. You did not ask any question. It is likely that I will know how to solve it. Or someone else will.

Comment: Dear @VladimirFГероямслава, Is it clear my question?

Comment: It was obvious that English is not your first language. I tried to improve the question in some way. The downvote your question received in the beginning was not from me but it probably reflected the too broad "code request" type of post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Fortran [`index`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html) function to scan the line for "BEST STSR" substring, then extract the number.

Here is an example:

```
program main
    implicit none
    character(128) :: line
    integer :: i, stat, unit
    real :: val
    
    open (FILE="data.txt", NEWUNIT=unit, STATUS="old", ACTION="read", IOSTAT=stat)
    if (stat /= 0) error stop "Cannot open file"
      
    do while (.true.)
        read (unit, "(a)", IOSTAT=stat) line
        if (stat /= 0) exit

        ! Scan buffer for keyword "BEST STSR". Extract number if keyword is found.
        i = index(line, "BEST STSR")
        if (i /= 0) then
            ! length("BEST STSR =") = 11
            read (line(i+11:), *, IOSTAT=stat) val
            if (stat /= 0) error stop "Cannot read value"

        end if
    end do
      
    close (unit)
    
end program main
```

Comment: `do while (.true.)` is realy superfluous, just `do` does the same. I would use the same approach for the parsing, it is the simplest one I can think of.